# Stan : Multivariate priors for hierarchical models whithout group-level predictors for prior mean

Tags: stan

I want to fit a Lotka-Volterra competition model with Stan.
I read the [section about multivariate hierarchical priors in the manual](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_27/stan-users-guide/multivariate-hierarchical-priors-section.html).

We have :

- "individual" = one observation of abundance of the focal species at time t
- "group" = focal species
- "predictors" = abundances of each species
- "outcomes" = focal species abundance increment between t and t+1
  (for people who know the model, for now I only try to infer the interaction matrix (alpha) and later I will add the species growth rate (but it's simpler since there is no need for multivariate)).

But in the manual, they add a "Group-level predictors for prior mean" in their Stan model.
I don't think I need this and I don't even see what it would be in my data (maybe I am wrong, tell me if it's the case !).
Therefore I tried to remove it. But I am very unsure about my model, especially with the mu, and would be glad if someone more experienced with these models could tell me if I am wrong.

```
data {
  int<lower=0> N;              // num individuals (generations)
  int<lower=1> K;              // num ind predictors (species)
  int<lower=1> J;              // num groups (species)
  int<lower=1,upper=J> jj[N];  // group for individual
  matrix[N, K] x;              // individual predictors
  vector[N] y;                 // outcomes
}
parameters {
  corr_matrix[K] Omega;        // prior correlation
  vector<lower=0>[K] tau;      // prior scale
  vector[K] beta[J];           // indiv coeffs by group
  vector[K] mu[J];            // mean coeff by group
  real<lower=0> sigma;         // prediction error scale
}
model {
  tau ~ cauchy(0, 2.5);
  Omega ~ lkj_corr(2);
  {
    for (j in 1:J)
      mu[J] ~ normal(0, 5);
      beta ~ multi_normal(mu, quad_form_diag(Omega, tau));
  }
  for (n in 1:N)
    y[n] ~ normal(x[n] * beta[jj[n]], sigma);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out a collegue told me that I can just keep the code as in the manual, and have only 1s in the u[J].
Seems obvious now ;)